# iOS build failure in PhoneGap Build "error: Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported"

Tags: ios, xcode, phonegap-build

iOS build failure in PhoneGap Build
`error: Compiling IB documents for earlier than iOS 7 is no longer supported`.

Last successful build was on Dec 3. It fails since Dec 7.

Got to know that XCode 9 will not support storyboards that are built for iOS version less than 7.

I changed `deployment-target` to `7.0` and the build was successful.

`<preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0"/>`

Need to know if there was any Phonegap Build Xcode update happened recently?

Answer (score 0):

iOS build issue is resolved and now I could create iOS builds successfully. No idea what happened yesterday with error though.